# How to obtain requested columns from select inside PL/pgSQL function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Is there any way to obtain the list of columns requested inside a Postgres function? By way of illustration:

```
create type a_type as (id int, val text, expensive int[]);

create function find_by_id(rid int) returns setof a_type as $$
  declare
    atyp a_type%rowtype;
  begin
    select id,val from a_table where id=rid into atyp.id,atyp.val;
    select array(select int_column from another_table where foreign_id=rid) into atyp.expensive;
    return next atyp;
  end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

This is populating the `int[]` field of the return type with a query to another table with a foreign key on our main table and is of course called with `select [COLUMN LIST] from find_by_id(ID)`. Is there any way of accessing `[COLUMN LIST]` from inside the function? If `expensive` is not specified in the column list then I do not need to do the second select and populate a field that is only going to be thrown away by Postgres before returning the result.

Comment: So basically you want your function to know what columns the calling query is selecting, without passing those column names to the function explicitly? If so then no, it can't be done. You'll have to supply them as an argument to the function.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'd assumed. It's not a great hassle to modify the function to take, say, a set of flags that the caller would provide as arguments if the expensive columns are specified (this is being driven by a Node/GraphQL front end) but it would be nice to keep the logic entirely within Postgres.